# How to create nested training and testing sets?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm working with the `ChickWeight` data set in R. I'm looking to create multiple models, each trained for an individual chick. As such, I am nesting the data so that a dataframe is created for each individual chick and stored within the list column.

Here is the start:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(datasets)
data("ChickWeight")

ChickWeightNest <- ChickWeight %>% 
  group_by(Chick) %>% 
  nest()
```

From here, training a linear regression model on all dataframes simultaneously is very easy by simply building the model as a function then mutating a new column and mapping. However, building a more sophisticated model (e.g. xgboost) requires first splitting the data into testing and training sets. How can I split my all nested data frames at once to create training and testing sets so that I can train multiple models simultaneously?

As a side note, info on training/tuning multiple models seems to be relatively sparse in my research, any related resources or past stack questions would be very appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this [Tidymodels nested resampling tutorial](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/work/nested-resampling/)

Answer (score 1):

The key here is realizing that each line of the nested data is a list and so you have to use list functions on it, for example `lapply` from base R or `map` from purrr.

Here's an example of how that would work using the `rsample` package to do the split (75% for training)

```
ChickWeightNest_example<- ChickWeightNest %>%
  mutate(data_split = purrr::map(data,
                       ~rsample::initial_split(.x, prop = .75))) %>%
  mutate(data_training_only= purrr::map(data_split,
                             ~rsample::training(.x)),
         data_testing_only= purrr::map(data_split, 
                             ~rsample::testing(.x))
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this where you first randomly sample train or test per chick in a new column to use later and group again to nest the data per group:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(datasets)
data("ChickWeight")

ChickWeight %>% 
  group_by(Chick) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(split = sample(c("train", "test"), n(), replace = FALSE)) %>%
  group_by(Chick) %>%
  nest() 
#> # A tibble: 50 × 2
#> # Groups:   Chick [50]
#>    Chick data             
#>    <ord> <list>           
#>  1 1     <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  2 2     <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  3 3     <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  4 4     <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  5 5     <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  6 6     <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  7 7     <tibble [12 × 4]>
#>  8 8     <tibble [11 × 4]>
#>  9 9     <tibble [12 × 4]>
#> 10 10    <tibble [12 × 4]>
#> # … with 40 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>